# Display problem depending on the customer's role - woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem on the "my account" page of my woocommerce store.
Indeed, when I log in with a **new customer account** that has **never placed an order**, I have 3 content containers that disappear.
After testing, they **only** appear if I place an order with the account in question.

Do you have any idea where this could be coming from?

The 3 divs in question correspond to :

- the navigation menu of the page my account that disappears only on the dashboard tab (it reappears on all other tabs - my orders, my addresses ...)
- a div with the recently viewed products (see code n°1 below)
- a div with the articles recently written by the customer (see code n°2 below)

When an order is placed, all the content reappears.
I also have a div with the recent orders which strangely, does not have any problem of display (see code n°3 below)

Do not hesitate to ask me for clarifications, or if you think that the error comes from a tag elsewhere in my code (a tag of authorization according to the role for example?)

In advance, Thank you very much for your help.

```
add_shortcode( 'recently_viewed_products', 'bbloomer_recently_viewed_shortcode' );
 
function bbloomer_recently_viewed_shortcode() {
 
   $viewed_products = ! empty( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ? (array) explode( '|', wp_unslash( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ) : array();
   $viewed_products = array_reverse( array_filter( array_map( 'absint', $viewed_products ) ) );
 
   if ( empty( $viewed_products ) ) return;
    ?>
<div class="col-23">
    <?php $title = '<h3>Produits consultés récemment</h3>';?>
    <?php $product_ids = implode( ",", $viewed_products );?>
 
   <?php return $title . do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids' limit='4' columns='4' orderby='post__in' class='recentes-vues']");?>
   
</div>
   
<?php }

function custom_track_product_view() {
    if ( ! is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $post;

    if ( empty( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) )
        $viewed_products = array();
    else
        $viewed_products = (array) explode( '|', $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] );

    if ( ! in_array( $post->ID, $viewed_products ) ) {
        $viewed_products[] = $post->ID;
    }

    if ( sizeof( $viewed_products ) > 15 ) {
        array_shift( $viewed_products );
    }

    // Store for session only
    wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', implode( '|', $viewed_products ) );
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_track_product_view', 20 );

// PRODUIT RECENT PAGE COMPTE
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard' , 'recentes_vues', 5 );
function recentes_vues() {
    echo do_shortcode('[recently_viewed_products]');
}
```

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard' , 'recent_posts', 3 );
function recent_posts() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in()) :

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    ?><div id="recentposts">
    <?php
      if ($author_posts->found_posts) {
      ?>
    <ul class="liststylenone">
    <?php
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>   
    <?php           
    endwhile;
    ?></ul><?php
      }
    else {
        echo '<p>Aucun article trouvé </p>';
    }
else :
   echo "not logged in";
endif;

?>
```

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'recent_order', 2 );
 function recent_order(){
    // For logged in users only
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // The current user ID

    // Get the WC_Customer instance Object for the current user
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

    // Get the last WC_Order Object instance from current customer
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

    if ( is_a( $last_order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
    $order_id     = $last_order->get_id(); // Get the order id
    $order_data   = $last_order->get_data(); // Get the order unprotected data in an array
    $order_status = $last_order->get_status(); // Get the order status
    $date_created  = $last_order->get_date_created();
    $order_total = $last_order->get_total();
    }
?>


<div class="row last-order">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="col-5">
        <div class="col-md-4 order-status-box">
      <h6 class="status">État : <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order_status ) ); ?></h6>
    </div>
        <p class="totalcmdd"><?php echo $order_total."€"; ?></p>
            <?php 
                setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
                date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
                echo utf8_encode(strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($date_created)));
                //echo date('d-F-Y', strtotime($date_created)); ?>
        </p>
            </div>
        
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;justify-content: space-evenly;align-items: center;margin-right: 1.5em;margin-left: 1.5em;padding: 0.3em;background-color: white;text-transform: uppercase;text-decoration: none;font-size: 13px;">
                
    <?php foreach ($last_order->get_items() as $item) :
  $product   = $item->get_product(); 
  $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array(50, 50));
  if ($product->get_image_id() > 0) {
    $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>'; // You had an extra variable here
  }
  echo $item_name . $item->get_name();
        endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: How you create new customer account ? Do you allow registrations without purchase ?

Comment: Yes, I allow the creation of accounts without purchase.
When a user is without an account, the "my account" page refers to the login and account creation forms.
If the user creates his account, this is where the dashboard is bugged. If he orders, then my divs are displayed as expected

Comment: I found the place where the error comes from: it is located in this PHP block but I don't know how to define it... Do you have an idea? ```<?php foreach ($last_order->get_items() as $item) :
  $product   = $item->get_product(); 
  $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array(50, 50));
  if ($product->get_image_id() > 0) {
    $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>'; // You had an extra variable here
  }
  echo $item_name . $item->get_name();
  endforeach;
?> ``` To see the code in context, you can look at the last code listed in my question above @MartinMirchev

Comment: And what is the error ? Turn on your debug and share what errors you get.

Comment: there is no error message, just that this piece of code makes some other blocks of the "my account" page disappear for users who don't have any order on their account (because this problematic block retrieves the data of the last order).
Are you talking about debugging logs?